# PHPMailer does not provide ErrorInfo

Tags: error-handling, sendmail, phpmailer

I have a problem with PHP Mailer, which is not providing the $mail->ErrorInfo when an error occured.
I tested with the original example from [http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=tutorial#1] as below.

```
<?php

require("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host     = "smtp.example.com"; // SMTP server

$mail->From     = "from@example.com";

$mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message";
$mail->Body     = "Hi! \n\n This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer.";
$mail->WordWrap = 50;

if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo 'Message was not sent.';
   echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
?>
```

I've set the host to my server, modified "from" and "AddAddress" to correct addresses and I've received the test mail as expected. But whhen I change the recipient address to blxxxa@blablaxxxx.de, just to check how the errors will be handled I don't get the error.

```
$mail->AddAddress("blxxxa@blablaxxxx.de");
```

I still receive "Message has been sent". Any Idea? Maybe server settings?

Comment: Don't use old code from worxware - get PHPMailer [from github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: I just tried the lastest code, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ErrorInfo` will not contain an error message unless an error happens. It sounds like your mail server is accepting the message without complaining (as would be expected if it's a relay or on localhost), so you need to check your mail server logs and your bounce mailbox since the problem is further upstream from you and thus not visible to PHPMailer.

In short, you're not doing anything wrong, you're just looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Yes! That's right! *argl* PHP Mailer cannot deliver mail failures like wrong domain or wrong mailaddress. It can just check the mails syntax.

Answer (score 4):

Try putting your $mail->Send() into a try-catch block.

```
 try{
      // ... Your Setup ...
      $mail->Send();
 } 
 catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage();  //PHPMailer error messages
 } 
 catch (Exception $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();  // other error messages
 }
```

if you look at the code of the phpmailer library ( [phpmailer library on github](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php) search for the **public function send()** code block )
 you'll see that phpmailer throws exceptions in case of failure.

You have some **good** examples here : http://www.merocode.com/sending-emails-using-phpmailer-via-smtp/

good luck.

Comment: It only throws exceptions if you enable them when creating the instance with `$mail = new PHPMailer(true);`. Otherwise it catches them internally.

Comment: I tried this way, too, but it still doesn't work. Maybe a server configuration? I'm a bit confused...

Answer (score 1):

Provide profer hostname, username and password. for example,

```
<?php

require("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host     = "mail.example.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 25; // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "username"; // SMTP account username example
$mail->Password   = "password";

$mail->From     = "from@example.com";

$mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message";
$mail->Body     = "Hi! \n\n This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer.";
$mail->WordWrap = 50;

if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo 'Message was not sent.';
   echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
?>
```

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to use authentication without encryption.

Answer (score 0):

In my case PhpMailer causes a warning at `$mail->send();`

> Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`mail.xxx.com' did not match expected CN=`mail.yyy.com'
>
> in class.smtp.php on line 368

So imho PhpMailer misses some exception handing here.
In such a case you have the following possibilities:

- Create an issue in the ticket system https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues and hope for an update
- add a "@" to the function call `@$mail->send();` - which hides the warning, but does not help you further
- Work with the PHP buffer to read out the warning.

**Update:**

In PHPMailer 6.x the warning was removed - but $mail->ErrorInfo does not contain any useful information. All I get is "SMTP connect() failed". Not really an improvement...

Comment: For tracking, I discuss in more detail the loss of useful error message at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70105353/phpmailer-this-smtp-error-info-is-overwritten-after-smtp-connect-fail-useful